# Multiple occurrences of bounding boxes around a same location

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I implemented the following code, to match nodes in a plant, using as template a small cropped image.

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread('Exp.2 - Florestópolis, 35DAE, 2017-2018, T4, R2, P4.jpg')
img_rgb = cv2.medianBlur(img_rgb, 7)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template_image = cv2.imread('TemplateNode.jpg',0)
template_image = cv2.medianBlur(template_image, 5)
width, height = template_image.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold =  0.6

locations = np.where(res >= threshold)

for position_tuple in zip(*locations[::-1]):

        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, position_tuple, (position_tuple[0] + width, position_tuple[1] + height), (0,255,0), 1)
```

However, it generates too many bounding boxes (tuples), around a same location, as show:

[image: Output Image from Template Matching]

So, there is a work around to solve this issue?

Comment: Look for nonmax(imum) suppression algorithm.

Comment: This occurs because slight shifts still match. You can mask out a region around each match in the match score result image before looking for the next one. Or use minMaxLoc() to find global max as described at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html and https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707. See also https://answers.opencv.org/question/165740/template-matching-multiple-objects/

Comment: Could you add your original input image and an expected output image? Also would be nice if you added your template image. If you're trying to detect the nodes in the image, an alternative approach would be to use morphological opening with an elliptical shaped kernel is isolate the nodes.

Comment: Added the original image, the template can be any cropped node from the image, but i will add it later anyway, because im away from the work computer. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach. Code is unlikely an efficient one. I think k-means clustering from some package may work better. Idea is to group together locations, which are too close:

```
def group_locations(locations, min_radius):
    x = locations[:, 0][ : , None]
    dist_x = x - x.T
    y = locations[:, 1][ : , None]
    dist_y = y - y.T
    dist = np.sqrt(dist_x**2 + dist_y**2)
    np.fill_diagonal(dist, min_radius+1)
    too_close = np.nonzero(dist <= min_radius)
    groups = []
    points = np.arange(len(locations))
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(points):
        groups.append([points[i]])
        for j in range(len(too_close[0])):
            if too_close[0][j] == points[i]:
                groups[i].append(too_close[1][j])
                points = np.delete(points, np.nonzero(points == too_close[1][j]))
        i += 1

    new_locations = []
    for group in groups:
        new_locations.append(np.mean(locations[group], axis=0))

    return np.array(new_locations)
```

So you take your locations and group them before plotting:

```
locations = []
size = 600
for _ in range(50):
    locations.append((random.randint(0, size), random.randint(0, size)))

locations = np.array(locations)
min_radius = 50

new_locations = group_locations(locations, min_radius)
#I run it second time as sometimes locations form chains which are longer than radius 
new_locations = group_locations(new_locations, min_radius) 
plt.scatter(locations[:, 0], locations[:, 1], c='blue', label='Original locations')
plt.scatter(new_locations[:, 0], new_locations[:, 1], c='red', marker='x', label='New grouped locations')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

actually tried it with image provided

```
img_rgb = cv2.imread('obsvu.jpg')
img_rgb = cv2.medianBlur(img_rgb, 7)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template_image = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
template_image = cv2.medianBlur(template_image, 5)
width, height = template_image.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold =  0.6

locations = np.where(res >= threshold)

new_locations = group_locations(np.array(locations).T, 50).T

for position_tuple in zip(*new_locations.astype(int)[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, position_tuple, (position_tuple[0] + width, position_tuple[1] + height), (0,255,0), 5)
```

Original locations: 723 
New locations: 6 (yep, template selection not the best)

[image: result]